Dense subspace of space of radial functions in $H^1_0(\Omega)$
Consider $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ a bounded domain. By definition, the space of radial functions in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is
$$
H^1_{0, \text{rad}}(\Omega) = \{u \in H^1_0(\Omega) : u = u \circ R, \forall R \in O(N)\}.
$$
It is very common  in papers the authors just say that $H^1_{0,\text{rad}}(\Omega) = \overline{C^\infty_{0,\text{rad}}(\Omega)}^{H^1_0(\Omega)}$, without more comments, where
$$
C^\infty_{0,\text{rad}}(\Omega) = \{u \in C^\infty_0(\Omega) : u \text{ is radial}\}.
$$
I am trying to find a precise proof of this. If we replace $\Omega$ by $\mathbb{R}^N$ I know how to prove using standad molifications. The hard part for me in the case of a bounded domain it is to conclude that the molification of a function in $H^1_{0,\text{rad}}(\Omega)$ has its support in $\Omega$.  It seems it is possible to use Haar measure to prove it, but I didn't find a reference with it.
In other words, given $u \in H^1_{0,\text{rad}}(\Omega)$, what to prove there exists a sequence $u_n \in C^\infty_{0,\text{rad}}(\Omega)$ such that $u_n \to u$ in $H^1_0(\Omega)$?
Any help with this or just a reference with this fact will be appreciated.
Edit: Consider $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ a bounded domain invariant under orthogonal transformations. For $u$ to be radial I mean,$u$ is invariant under any orthogonal map in $\mathbb{R}^N$.

If you know something about it with a ball, it would help me a lot. However I fixed the typo, I mean, $\Omega$ is a bounded domain.

I just edited what you pointed out. Thank you. I want to  use any orthogonal map, not just ratations.

The inclusion $\overline{C^\infty_{0,\text{rad}}(\Omega)}^{H^1_0(\Omega)} \subset H^1_{0,\text{rad}}(\Omega)$ is trivial.
For the reverse inclusion take $u \in H^1_{0,\text{rad}}(\Omega)$ and observe that $u(x)=\int_{O(N)}u(Rx) dO(R)$, where $dO$ is the normalized Haar measure of $O(N)$. If $u_n \in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ and $u_n$ converges to $u$ in $H^1_0$ then $v_n:=\int_{O(N)}(u_n \circ R) dO(R) \in C^\infty_{0,rad}(\Omega)$ and $v_n$ converges to $u=\int_{O(N)}(u \circ R) dO(R)$ in $H^1_0$.

Thank you! Could you please give a reference with the results: 1) $u_n \in C^\infty_0(\Omega) $    2) $u_n \to u$ in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ ?

That is the very definition of $H^1_0$, see for example 'Partial Differential Equations' by Evans.

Another question, could you please recommend a reference with the proof that $u (x) = \int_{O(N)} u (Rx) d O(R)$ if $u \in H^1_{0,\text{rad}}(\Omega)$ ? Also, I would like a reference with the details that $v_n$ is smooth and converges to $u$.

To the best of my knowledge those details aren't worked out in any book (if you are very lucky you might find it in some online notes). They are excellent exercises in measure and integration theory. I would highly recommend you try it yourself and ask questions on MSE if you get stuck.
